# Pinnacle DC 10+ does not work properly

Tags: 12.04, drivers, video

I have an old card - Pinnacle DC-10 plus. Some time ago I didn't have any problem with this device. Ubuntu recognized it O'k and I used TVtime for watching clips I got from an external video device. So then I didn't use the card for sometime.. Today I tried it again but I got a noised green capture.. I guessed that the problem was with my card. So I rebooted to an old WinXP and installed the necessary drivers and software. I found my DC10 worked Ok. The picture was clean.
I returned to Ubuntu (12.04 - updated) and looked through logs. I found this in syslog: "Jan  7 01:57:35 UHOST01 kernel: [ 2730.078836] DC10plus[0]: VIDIOC_CROPCAP - subcapture only supported for compressed capture".
The message repeated many times. It appears just when I've started the application uses the device (vlc, TVtime, xawtv...)
Some investigations were performed but the problem is still actual for me. Please help me to get it repaired.

The driver is: zoran
$ v4l2-ctl --info
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : zoran
    Card type     : DC10plus[0]
    Bus info      : PCI:0000:02:05.0
    Driver version: 0.0.0
    Capabilities  : 0x04000007
        Video Capture
        Video Output
        Video Overlay
        Streaming

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest contacting the publisher of the Linux driver, Ronald, linked from [this web page](http://mjpeg.sourceforge.net/driver-zoran/development.php) to see if he has a fix for the driver for SECAM use on modern versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've written a letter to Roland :-)